# Why doesn't file size always change when I adjust JpegBitmapEncoder QualityLevel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jpeg

I am trying to save a WritableBitmap, and make sure the resulting file is below a certain size. My code is as follows

```
//Fetch Image from file
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("YourImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
WriteableBitmap writableBitmapImage = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

//initialize variables and values
MemoryStream stream;
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder;
byte[] result;
int quality = 100;

//loop through save process, checking file size and changing quality
while (selected.maxFileSize < result.Length && quality > 1)
{
    encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    stream = new MemoryStream();
    encoder.QualityLevel = quality;
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(
        ReplaceTransparency(writableBitmapImage, Colors.White))
    );
    encoder.Save(stream);
    result = stream.GetBuffer();
    if (quality > 5) quality += -5;
    else quality--;
}
```

When I run this code, I don't see any file size changes from the starting point of `QualityLevel = 100;` to `QualityLevel = 10;`.

At `QualityLevel = 5;` I see a large change in file size.

Is there any way to control file size more granularly?

Comment: Hm, you're not really writing a white rectangle, are you?

Comment: Why are you creating and setting up `encoder` only to throw it away? You never write at `QualityLevel == 100` in your sample code. Also, what is in `writableBitmapImage`?

Comment: @TaW You are correct, I am not writing a white rectangle. writableBitmapImage is an existing WritableBitmap image. I wasn't sure how to represent that in the question.

Comment: @NetMage I am setting up the encoder, only to delete so I can set the encoder.QualityLevel before entering into the while loop. writableBitmapImage contains an existing image, usually a headshot or portrait. I wasn't sure the best way to show that in the code. I had to construct the code above out of a much larger program.

Comment: @NetMage I have edited the code for clarity

Comment: I modified the code to test `stream.Length` and used `TryGetBuffer` to get the right length buffer into `result` when found. Dumping the length output it goes down consistently when I test (except a peak at 75 which is due to a Windows bug) using two different images, so perhaps something is happening in `ReplaceTransparency` that I don't have the code for. Since JPEG files can't have transparency, I wonder what you are doing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`MemoryStream.GetBuffer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused. For example, if the string "test" is written into the MemoryStream object, the length of the buffer returned from GetBuffer is 256, not 4, with 252 bytes unused. To obtain only the data in the buffer, use the ToArray method; however, ToArray creates a copy of the data in memory.

Then use `.ToArray()` instead.

Comment: Or just use `MemoryStream.Length` to determine actual length.